# ¿Como cierro sesion en php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo implementado un logout pero no me cierra la sesion y no me redirige a la pagina principal.

Este es mi enrutador.

```
include('controllers/sistema.php');
include_once("view/img.php");

$action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : "login";

switch($action){
    case 'logout':
        $sistema->logout();
        include_once('view/login/index.php');
        break;
```

Este es mi metodo principal en la clase sistema donde esta la conexion a la base de datos y validaciones de usuario

```
 public function logout()
    {
        unset($_SESSION['logeado']);
        session_destroy();
    }
```

Aca tengo mi action en mi menú

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="login.php?action=logout">Cerrar Sesión</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes redirigirte a tu vista principal luego del **`session_destroy()`** en tu función **`logout()`** y luego usar la función [**`exit()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php) para asegurarte de que el código se detenga después de realizar la redirección, por ejemplo:

```
public function logout()
{
   unset($_SESSION['logeado']);
   session_destroy();
   header("Location: view/login/index.php");
   exit();
}
```

Y ya no vendría necesario el `include_once` que tienes en tu `case`:

```
case 'logout':
     $sistema->logout();
break;
```

Otra forma más correcta y segura de hacerlo sería así:

```
public function logout()
{
   session_start(); // Iniciamos la sesión existente.
   session_unset(); // Luego eliminamos las variables de sesión.
   session_destroy(); // Luego destruimos la sesión.
   header('Location: view/login/index.php'); // Y por último nos redirigimos a la vista principal.
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Me dice Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. :c

Comment: @Luis Asegúrate de poner la URL correcta en el header. Me avisas si te funciona o si tienes algún otro problema.